# Couldn't Start UWP project in Xamrin Forms

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, win-universal-app, xamarin.uwp

I am starting my first Xamarin Forms application using Visual Studio 2015. The default template provided 6 Project. (Android,iOS,PCL,UWP,8.1,windows phone).

All the projects works correctly including the Android,8.1,Windows Phone Emulator.

But when i try to deploy the UWP project , breaks (Exception) at the first statement where it calls the MainPage inside PCL. This happens in both Local Machine and Emulator. (debug Mode , All CPU).

I have already updated xamarin forms to the latest stable release, updated Visual Studio but i am not able to resolve the issue.

Exception:

> An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not find Windows Runtime type
>   'Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar'.

Please Help

Answer (score 4):

The `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar` is a type that is only available in the Windows Mobile Extension SDK and you have to reference this SDK for it to be available.

Right-click your UWP project in the Solution Explorer, select `Add` -> `Reference`, then under Universal Windows select Extensions and find `Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP`. Check the one that matches the targeted Windows 10 build version of your app.

You also need to use the `IsTypePresent` API, which will check at runtime if the type is available on the current device. This is important, because `StatusBar` does not exist on any other version of Windows 10 than on Mobile:

```
if(ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar") )
{
   //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like issue in xamarin UWP concept , are you updated Xamain.Forms ?
Goto Tools-> NuGet Package manager -> Manage Package for Solution -> Microsoft.NETCore.Universal Windows Platform -> update latest version.

after updated all , still same problem please check here some around 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64731/how-to-solve-unknown-type-in-uwp-app-windows-ui-viewmanagement-statusbar

Comment: Yes i have updated but it still doesn't work. I will read the link and try to figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If none of this work try updating your windows SDK to the latest version. It worked for me. I also added the reference to `Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP`.

**EDIT:**

I also have experimented that sometimes when you update visual studio it fails again. I had to manually change de SDK version in my UWP project, going to Properties > Application > Target Version > Select latest version